# libbaccats-7.0.5.so => not found

Tags: linux, backup, bacula, libraries

I'm installing Bacula from sources on CentOS 6.6.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc/bacula --with-mysql

[root@bacula0 lib]# ldd /usr/sbin/bacula-dir 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff65bff000)
    libbacfind-7.0.5.so => /usr/lib/libbacfind-7.0.5.so (0x00007ff210081000)
    libbacsql-7.0.5.so => /usr/lib/libbacsql-7.0.5.so (0x00007ff20fe58000)
    libbaccats-7.0.5.so => not found
    libbaccfg-7.0.5.so => /usr/lib/libbaccfg-7.0.5.so (0x00007ff20fc4c000)
```

You can see that one library is missing. I have run `ldconfig -v`. Also there is lists of libs:

```
[root@bacula0 lib]# ls -l /usr/lib/libbacc*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     19 Mar 11 15:17 /usr/lib/libbaccats-7.0.5.so -> libbaccats-mysql.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    952 Mar 11 15:17 /usr/lib/libbaccats.la
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  84957 Mar 11 15:17 /usr/lib/libbaccats-mysql-7.0.5.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   1027 Mar 11 15:17 /usr/lib/libbaccats-mysql.la
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     25 Mar 11 15:17 /usr/lib/libbaccats-mysql.so -> libbaccats-mysql-7.0.5.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     19 Mar 11 15:17 /usr/lib/libbaccats.so -> libbaccats-7.0.5.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 130362 Mar 11 15:17 /usr/lib/libbaccfg-7.0.5.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    976 Mar 11 15:17 /usr/lib/libbaccfg.la
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     18 Mar 11 15:17 /usr/lib/libbaccfg.so -> libbaccfg-7.0.5.so
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I fix this by creating symlinc

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libbaccats-mysql.so /usr/lib64/libbaccats-7.0.5.so
```